# forEach not waiting until the promise resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, callback

Anyone help me out for this? The loop goes to the next index before the promise resolved for the current index.
Here is my code

```
 let images = [
     {
         uri : 'file1://.....',
     },
     {
         uri : 'file2://.....',
         isBase64:true,
         base64:'ATDDJWUDUWDUDGIHDIHDI'
     },
     {
        uri : 'file3://.....',
     }
 ];

 imageProcessing().then(()=>{
    console.log('All done')
})

 imageProcessing = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    images.forEach(async (element, index) => {
      await convertUriToBase64(element, index);
      if(images.length -1 === index){
          resolve();
      }
    });
});
  };

  let convertUriToBase64 = (element,index) => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
      if(element.isBase64){
        let base64 =  await doSomeAsyncStuff(element.uri,'base64'); // got base64 
        images[index].base64 = base64;
        images[index].isBase64 = true;
        console.log(index + ' done');
        resolve();
      }
      else{
        console.log(index + ' done');
          resolve(); // resolve if already it is in base64 format
      }
    });
  };
```

Possible to get it to work like this? I got output like this

0 done
2 done
All done
1 done

**Expected output**

```
0 done
1 done
2 done
All done
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't use async with foreach,  replace with a `for of` instead.

Comment: @Keith, Thanks a lot. It works. could you please tell me why it does not work with forEach and map?

Comment: It's because `forEach` is a synchronous function, it has no concept of Promises.